# позиционирование текста в блоке

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

На макете я увидела что текст заканчивается на слове "block" (смотрите на скрин), но когда я добавила текст в html и добавила к нему css. У меня на сайте этот же текст заканчивается на слове "we". Что сделать, чтобы это исправить?
P.s специально убрала шрифт
[image: макет]

```css
body {
  background: #87509c;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 42.16px;
  color: #f7f3ea;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 910px;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  Hi there! We are the new kids on the block and we build awesome websites and mobile apps.
</div>
```

Comment: Добавить `<br>` после слова **block**?

Comment: Или просто разные `div` или `span` и стилями разделить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: #87509c;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5vw;
  color: #f7f3ea;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  Hi there! We are the new kids on the block<br> and we build awesome websites and mobile apps.
</div>
```